# similar of json_agg sql query using mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, json

```
    query = "SELECT key, json_agg(distinct value) as values FROM {}, jsonb_each(to_jsonb({})) GROUP BY key"
```

I have this above sql query to fetch data from postgres database.
This query works fine in postgres database.

Is there any similar query to make it

```
    mysql> select * from soubhagyairisdata;
    +-------+------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
    | index | id   | sepallengthcm | sepalwidthcm | unnamed:_3 | petalwidthcm | species     |
    +-------+------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
    |     0 |   47 |           5.1 |          3.8 |        1.6 |          0.2 | setosa      |
    |     1 |   48 |           4.6 |          3.2 |        1.4 |          0.2 | setosa      |
    |     2 |   49 |           5.3 |          3.7 |        1.5 |          0.2 | jennifer    |
    |     3 |   50 |             5 |          3.3 |        1.4 |          0.2 | setosa      |
    |     4 |   97 |            12 |          2.9 |        4.2 |          1.3 | jennifer    |
    |     5 |   98 |           6.2 |          2.9 |        4.3 |          1.3 | jennifer    |
    |     6 |   99 |           5.1 |          2.5 |          3 |          1.1 | kajol       |
    |     7 |  100 |            11 |          2.8 |          7 |          1.3 | floaw       |
    |     8 |  101 |           6.3 |          3.3 |          6 |          2.5 | Iris-flower |
    |     9 |  102 |           5.8 |          2.7 |        5.1 |          1.9 | Iris-flower |
    +-------+------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Here is my sample data

```
    mysql> SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(species) FROM soubhagyairisdata;
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | JSON_ARRAYAGG(species)                                                                                             |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | ["setosa", "setosa", "jennifer", "setosa", "jennifer", "jennifer", "kajol", "floaw", "Iris-flower", "Iris-flower"] |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need these for all columns witlout passing column name

Comment: what do you mean without passing column name?  then how you know which columns needs to be used to create the json string?

Comment: Please check my postgres query i shared in question. There i am not passing any column name

Comment: is that query valid? to me seems like that query won't run at all.

Comment: That works on postgres shell

Comment: I doubt it works , I even ran it in shell to make sure

Answer (score 3):

yes,

you can use [JSON_OBJECTAGG(key, value)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg)
or [JSON_ARRAYAGG(col_or_expr)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

Comment: If i don't know the column names how can i get that ?
Can you please write full query ?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output to your question plus maybe table structure

Comment: Updated question please check

Answer (score 2):

Hello if you need write all query in json structure in mariadb or mysql you need create all column to pair key and value how this

```
select JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT( 'id', tmu.id, 'name', tmu.name, 'orders', case when json_orders is null then '[]' else json_orders end,'pool', o2.idpool ) ) as json
```

Same this example. i hope help you see ya.